# Linking Access database to Excel pivot table, when Database is saved on a shared network drive

Tags: excel, ms-access, pivot-table, data-connections, network-shares

I have been working on linking an MS access database to an excel pivot table. The MS access is saved to a file share, which on my computer is mapper to an *"S"* drive.

**Problem:**

After I finished making the report I sent it around but it didn't work for others because the connection was to the *"S:"* drive which is not available on other people's computers. I changed the connection on the connection properties to the actual network name, but I still get the same error when others try it. It works fine for me though.

**Error:**

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 'S:______accbd' is not a valid path. 
Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected 
to the server on which the file resides
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenny.

I would follow the method of elimination to solve this problem.

1) Map other users' S drives to the same network share location as yours.
2) A more elegant solution would be to use actual network location for your Access file.
3) If step # 2 doesn't work, I would test users' access to the network location of the Access file. You might need to have your network admin grant them read privileges to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

what version of access you are using?

try also in MS Access: 
turn on in options "Allow trusted locations on my network (not recomended)
and then add your network location to list of "trusted locations".